# iOS Safari and PhoneGap app crashes if the content is larger than 4000-5000 px

Tags: html, css, safari, cordova

I'm developing a PhoneGap application. In iOS 5.1.1 there was no problem but in 6.1.3 there is a scrolling issue.

If I use a container with `overflow:auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;` and the content is larger than 4000-5000 px, Safari crashes after scrolling.

You can test it with the link below. Click the map and scroll it after zooming in 4-5 times.

http://okngnr.com/arb/

I know the problem is not SVG or too many DOM elements. Is there a bug in iOS 6.x? How can I see the crash report of Safari? I'm using Windows and these isn't CrashReporter under `\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\Logs\`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an iOS issue. Did you test on iOS 7 (for having an idea) ? On Mac, using Xcode Phonegap project and the debugger, you might have more informations. Maybe the problem comes when you load in one time all the content.

If you paginate ? Four by four with a button in the bottom to load others. It's not cool for your interface but if it's an iOS issue, you may not have the choice...

Comment: Thanks for reply. I don't think it is performance issue because I tested it on a simple page. As you said I need to test it on Mac and see the debugger.